# preg_replace to add something before end of HTML attr

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Right now, I can use `preg_replace` to add something at the beginning of an HTML attribute this way:

```
$output = preg_replace('/class="/', 'class="$new_class, $output, 1);
```

How can I add something at the end of the HTML attribute?

Comment: You should match everything in between double quotation marks `preg_replace('/(class="[^"]*)/', "\1 $new_class", $output);`

Comment: can you post `$output` and `$new_class` values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your regex to:

```
(class="[^"]*)
```

which means capturing a `class="` and everything else up to a double quotation mark `"`. Then use `\1` back-reference to first capturing group in replacement string for appending new class to it:

```
preg_replace('/(class="[^"]*)/', "$1 $new_class", $output);
```

[PHP live demo](http://ideone.com/YmXmsJ)

Comment: Doesn't work! Looks like there's something wrong with the second parameter "\1 $new_class".

Comment: Works now! Thanks! But I want it for the first occurrence of class attribute only. ($output could have multiple HTML tags with multiple class attribues).

Comment: Then go for forth argument of `preg_replace` as you did in your question `preg_replace('/(class="[^"]*)/', "$1 $new_class", $output, 1);`